# Can I connect a pull-up to a open drain output with current source ? Using LTC4124 charge controller

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, open-drain

On the [LTC4124](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc4124.pdf) there is a CHRG pin connected to an LED. Datasheet says it is a open drain but indicates a current source between source and ground. Could I use a pull up resistor connected to VCC and microcontroller instead of an LED ?

I am just not sure what is the limitations caused by the current source. Is this just to indicate that the max current that can be sinked is 300 uA ?

Thanks

[image: Showing current source as indicated on datasheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in the datasheet indicates that it should be possible.

As long as the CHRG pin pull-up is not above the chip VCC pin voltage and the current needed to pull CHRG voltage down to 0.4V at 200uA is not exceeded, it should work.

Which basically means the pull-up should be connected between chip VCC pin and CHRG so it stays always within limits of VCC, and resistance should just be quite high in value, more than 26k ohms.

Comment: Thanks ! I appreciate your feedback